# Return data from chained observables in resolver, wait until all data is fetched

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an Angular resolver to provide data for a component.
I am using ngrx. I want to check if 2 pieces of data (a car and its maker) are in the store, if they are not, dispatch an action to get the data from 2 separate APIs. I first get the car based on a url param, once I have the car I need to get the maker sending the car ID to the API.
Once both requests are done and I have both the car and its maker, I want to combine the data (add the maker as a property of the car) and return the car object in the resolver.

```
export class CardResolverService implements Resolve <Observable<any>> {

    private cardId: string;
    private cardLoaded$ = new Subject();
    private makerLoaded$ = new Subject();
    private car: Car;

    constructor(private store: Store<any>) {

    }

    // Check if car is in store, otherwise dispatch action to call API
    // Once the car is loaded, get its maker based on one of its properties
    private initCar(): void {
        this.store.select(CarSelectors.getCardById(this.cardId)).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.cardLoaded$)
        ).subscribe((car) => {
            if (!car) {
                this.store.dispatch(new CarSelectors.LoadCarByIdAction(this.cardId));
            } else {
                this.cardLoaded$.next(true);
                this.car = car;
                this.getCarMaker(car.makerId);
            }
        });
    }

    private getCarMaker(makerId: string) {
        this.store.select(MakerSelectors.getMakerById(makerId)).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.makerLoaded$)
        ).subscribe((maker) => {
            if (!maker) {
                this.store.dispatch(new MakerActions.LoadMakerByIdAction(makerId));
            } else {
                this.car.maker = maker;
                this.makerLoaded$.next(true);
            }

        });
    }

    // I need to wait until both car and maker are loaded to return the car object
    private waitForData(): Observable<TeamMemberView> {
        return this.carLoaded$.pipe(
                withLatestFrom(this.makerLoaded$),
                map(() => this.car)
        );

    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        // Get car ID from url
        this.carId = route.params['carId'];
        this.initCar();
        return this.waitForData(); // Here is where I need help
    }
}
```

In the waitForData method I am trying to check if both observables to get the car and the maker have returned a value, via subjects, and if they have, return the car object. But the waitForData method is not returning anything.

Comment: You can use something like [`forkjoin()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin), If you want the latest values use [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest)

Comment: Thanks but where do I need to use combineLatest? If I add that to the subjects it still doesn't work. I can't use forkJoin with the selectors because the second one can only be made once the first one is done.

Comment: if you can share it stackblitz, people can help modifying it.

Comment: So when both data you need are not present you want to postpone the Observable? Can you make https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve? I don't understand how is what you described related to the code you posted.